# Java Scanner delimiters help

Tags: java, delimiter, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read the following input with Scanner:

```
a -> b; 
c -> d; 
e -> f;
g -> h;
i -> j;
```

and I want my output to be:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

I already tried:

```
s.replaceAll("[->;]", "").trim();
```

and

```
sc.useDelimiter("[->;]");
```

But everytime I see this:

```
a

b
c

d
e

f
g

h
```

So I get 12 characters(spaces included of course) instead of 8. Does anyone know how to solve this? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\s*->\\s*|;\\s*");
```

The code:

```
String text = "a -> b; \n" +
      "c -> d; \n" +
      "e -> f;\n" +
      "g -> h;\n" +
      "i -> j; ";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\s*->\\s*|;\\s*");
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

prints:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

Or even `sc.useDelimiter("[->\\s;]+")` if none of `[->\\s;]` can be a part of the tokens you're interested in.